# IIS Rewrite for angular app in a virtual directory

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to build a web api project with an angular front end following this example https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015. In it, it states that you need to configure your web.config with

```
<rewrite>
 <rules>
  <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/src/" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

That works fine when my web api project is at www.example.com, but in my IIS setup it needs to be in a virtual directory at www.example.com/myApp. I have tried things like changing the action url to /myapp/src/ and other combinations, but it never redirects to the src folder my angular app is in. I have tried removing one or both of the conditions, which will then point to my src folder but then every request for my bundle.js files just returns the index.html file again.

Comment: Same for me ! Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Same for me ! Have you found any solution ?